# C create Makefile: how to set CFLAGS and LDFLAGS

Tags: c, compilation, makefile, linker, ldflags

I have simple modbus master project written in C99 C. Now I am compiling my application using (it works good):

```
$ gcc -std=c99 -O2 -Wall -I/usr/include/modbus test.c -o test -L/usr/lib/modbus -L/usr/include/curl -lmodbus -lm -lcurl
```

I would like to write classic Makefile. I try this:

```
CFLAGS=-std=c99 -O2 -Wall -I/usr/include/modbus 
LDFLAGS=-L/usr/lib/modbus -L/usr/include/curl -lmodbus -lm -lcurl

test: test.o
    $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) test.o -o test
test.o: test.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c test.c

clean:
    rm *.o test
```

but if I run `make` it crash on:

```
cc -L/usr/lib/modbus -L/usr/include/curl -lmodbus -lm -lcurl test.o -o test
test.o: In function `myFunction':
test.c:(.text+0x80): undefined reference to `log'
```

Where I have an error? What differences are between `CFLAGS` and `LDFLAGS`? `CFLAGS` is for compiler and `LDFLAGS`is for linker? How can I determine from my first `gcc` command what is param for compiler and which is for linker?

Comment: As shown in the question marked as duplicate, your LDFLAGS is in the wrong place. It should at least come *after* the .o files.

Comment: `$(CC) test.o $(LDFLAGS) -o test` works. Thank you!
But I still don't know what params are for linker/compiler.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by that

Comment: For example: `-L/usr/lib/modbus` is for `LDFLAGS` or `CFLAGS`?

Comment: -L specifies where to search for libraries, libraries are used at the linking stage, so you'll need that in LDFLAGS